# Output result of formula on different cell without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Is it possible to output the result of a formula on a different cell without the use of VBA and without directly reffering to the cell containing the formula (e.g. writting `=C1` into the output cell)?

I know that this can be easily done with the help of VBA, but I was wondering if there really is no simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: May i know the reason you want to output the result on a different cell?

Comment: I want to prevent users of the sheet to unintentionally delete the formula when they delete the data in the sheet.

Comment: i think direct referring to the cell containing the formula is the easiest way. You just need to refer and hide the formula column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, if you dont want VBA then all I can think of is to lock the cells so they can't be updated.

[How to lock just a range of cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-bdb8252f-d605-45cb-9712-137925867ad4)

Comment: I went for this solution since there really seems to be no other one without VBA.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know all formulas display their results within the cell they occupy.

if you want to pull a value from a cell without directly referencing the cell address, you could indirectly by using the offset function. However even the offset function needs to reference at least one cell on the worksheet.